# Changing validation on NgbDatepicker to allow blank entries

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I've integrated the datepicker into my project and attached it to an input/text field.

I need to allow incoming and outgoing empty strings (i.e. model is null, since these are manually passed through the `NgbDateParserFormatter` at `ngOnInit` and `onSubmit`) but the default validator considers this entry invalid.

I've looked around but haven't found a comprehensible way to change this behaviour. Help?

Comment: The model starts out as null in the [sample page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker). Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes, it starts empty. But the problem is that an empty field fails validation. So while it starts that way, you can't submit the form until a date is entered.

Answer (score 3):

First I  tried it like that, because the input associated with datepicker is of type "text": `dateControl: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}, null)`

I didn't work. But it worked when I set initial value to null: `dateControl: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: false}, null)`

Hope it will work with you.

Comment: Setting initial value to null worked for me ;) Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me in Angular 11